# Ubuntu 17.10 - shortcut to show me window with all key. shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, shortcuts

Does Ubuntu 17.10 have as Ubuntu 16.xx keyboard shortcuts window and to shows all keyboard shortcuts? 
As this one:

[image]

Super key shows me all tabs.

Comment: No, it has not, because it runs a different DE and that feature you mentioned is part of Unity only.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thank you. I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Shortcut key help for Ubuntu 18.04]I got so fed up with hunting for this page in the help that I made my own. Just cut & paste the following into spreadsheet/document and change the column widths to suit. Would be good to have similar help page on latest Ubuntu.

Launcher            Switching

Super (Press)   Open Launcher, displays shortcuts.      Alt + Tab   Switch between applications.
Alt + F1    Open Launcher keyboard navigation mode.     Alt + ` Switch between instances of current application.
Super + Tab Switch applications via Launcher.
Super + 1 to 9  Same as clicking on Launcher icon.      Workspaces
Super + Shift +1 to 9   Open new window of the app.
Super + S   Spread workspaces.
Activities          Ctrl + Alt + Up or Down Cursor  Switch workspaces.
Shift + Ctrl + Alt + Cursor Keys    Moves focus to different workspace.
Super (Tap) Open Activities Overview.
Super + A   Open Apps.      Windows
Ctrl + Tab  Switches between Activities.
Cursor Keys Moves the focus.        Ctrl + D    Minimise all windows.
Enter & Return  Open currently focused item.        Super + Up  Maximise the current window.
Super + Down    Restores or minimises current window.
HUD & Menu Bar          Super + Left or Right Cursor    Snap window to Left or Right
Alt + F4    Close active window
Super + F10 Open Application Menu.      Alt + Space Opens accessibility menu.
Cursor Left or Right    Moves focus between indicators.
Cursor Left or Right    Moves focus between indicators.     Tabs
Cursor Left or Right    Moves focus between indicators.
ctrl + Tab or Up or Down Cursor Move between tabs (e.g. in Web Browser)
ctrl + w    Close tab.